# How to remove this error :(-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to extract frames from vedio using opencv 4.1.2 in spyder python 3.7.1.But I am getting this error.

Code:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('‪G:/TSR/TSR_vedios/blur/01_01_01_02_01.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True
while success:
  cv2.imwrite("G:/TSR/TSR_vedios/tlevels/blurness/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)    
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  print ('Read a new frame: ', success)
  count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `open` function and also make sure that the image is a valid one, i.e. width and height is > 0.

Modify your code like this:

```py
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture()
success = vidcap.open('‪G:/TSR/TSR_vedios/blur/01_01_01_02_01.mp4')
if not success:
    print("Failed to open the video")

count = 0
while success:
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    height, width, channels = img.shape
    if (height > 0) and (width > 0):
        cv2.imwrite("G:/TSR/TSR_vedios/tlevels/blurness/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)    
        print('Read a new frame: ', success)
    else:
        print("Empty image")
    count += 1
```